# capturing the response(which is JSON ) of URL

Tags: ajax

I have one URL e.g(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=karvenagar&destinations=nalstop&mode=driving&language=en-US&key=YOUR_API_KEY). If I put this url in browser then it will give me resultant json. I want to capture this json in one variable in my javascript code.
my code is as follows:

```
      $.ajax({
    type : "Get",
    url :"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=karvenagar&destinations=nalstop&mode=driving&language=en-US&key=AIzaSyD6dUpr5eFqhHXUOfrzBERCTXeHAvX0Bpo",
    dataType :"jsonp",
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod",
    success : myJsonMethod = function(data){
        console.log(data);},
    error : function(httpReq,status,exception){
        console.log(status+" "+exception);
    }
});
```

but this is showing an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : parsererror Error: myJsonMethod was not called

I have followed some solution link on stackOverflow and https://m.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/1y57w7/jquery_ajax_syntax_issues/  but it is not helpful to resolve the issue. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just added &jsonp=MyCallbackFunction parameter in url and it worked for me.
So instead of 
url :"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=karvenagar&destinations=nalstop&mode=driving&language=en-US&key=AIzaSyD6dUpr5eFqhHXUOfrzBERCTXeHAvX0Bpo"

i have added 
url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=karvenagar&destinations=nalstop&mode=driving&jsonp=MyCallbackFunction&language=en-US&key=AIzaSyD6dUpr5eFqhHXUOfrzBERCTXeHAvX0Bpo"